# Whats wrong with my RSA implementation

Tags: c++, c, encryption, rsa

I wrote a small implementation of RSA encryption but it doesn't give the correct result ,sometimes the decryption gives 0 when using other values for p & q (primes). What could be wrong here ?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
 #define uint unsigned long long
uint modpow(uint base,uint exp,uint modulus)
{
  base %= modulus;
  unsigned long long result = 1;
  while (exp > 0) {
    if (exp & 1) result = (result * base) % modulus;
    base = (base * base) % modulus;
    exp >>= 1;
  }

  return result;
}
uint modinv(uint a,uint p) {
    uint ex = p-2, result = 1;
    while (ex > 0) {
        if (ex % 2 == 1) {
            result = (result*a) % p;
        }
        a = (a*a) % p;
        ex /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    uint p = 4294967291;
    uint q = 1073741789;
    uint e = 3;
    uint m = p*q;
    uint phi = (p -1)*(q -1);
    uint d = modinv(e,phi);
    uint c = 0x41424344;
    uint en = modpow(c,e,m);
    printf("Encrypting: %llX\nEncrypted: %llX\nDecrypted: %llX",c,en,modpow(en,d,m));
}
```

Comment: `phi` and `e` must be coprime, which they appear to be here ((p-1)*(q-1) = 4611685857366114520 with factors of: 2 2 2 5 7 19 2341 16381 22605091), but may not be for other arbitrary `p` and `q` primes.

Comment: I choose the prime such as "prime % e != 1" (e is a prime) but that's not the case ,i don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: You may have other issues, but what you said doesn't seem to match the requirement I gave. What is *the* prime? You need three primes such that `(p-1)*(q-1) % e != 0`.

Comment: Select a value of e from {3, 5, 17, 257, 65537}
    repeat
       p ← genprime(k/2)
    until (p mod e) ≠ 1
    repeat
       q ← genprime(k - k/2)
    until (q mod e) ≠ 1
    N ← pq
    L ← (p-1)(q-1)
    d ← modinv(e, L)
    return (N, e, d)
http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#note1
It doesn't say that (p -1)*(q -1) % e != 0. and the primes choosen are in the code inside main function.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize those relationships were equivalent. I'm out of ideas, then, sorry.

Comment: `base * base` overflow?

Comment: You have conveniently divided your program up into methods which can be tested independently.  **Have you tested each method independently**?  One of them is giving the wrong answer; start feeding in problems that you know the solutions to and see which one gives wrong answers.

Comment: Please don't create macros with lowercase names. You'll be sent to a special hell with the developers of winapi. Also, a typedef works just fine in this case.

Comment: @HMVC `uint m = p*q;` Given the values of `p` and `q`, that must be one mighty big `uint m` you have there.  Did you not check to see if this was even valid (read, `overflowed`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `unsigned long long` is probably only 64 bits, and the intermediates `result*base` and `base*base` can easily overflow 64 bits in your `modpow` function.  You need an `__int128` intermediate type here (if your compiler supports it).

Another problem is that RSA only works for plaintext/cipphertext values that map to integers that are NOT mulitples of p or q.  If you choose a plaintext that is a multiple of p or q, the decryption will fail.  This is not a problem with realistic (large) moduli, as the likelyhood of hitting a multiple of p or q randomly is astronomically small (its roughly the same as the chance of guessing the private key given only the public key).

The first problem is probably what is causing you grief.